# Graceful shutdown of ZMQ proxy

Tags: c++, proxy, zeromq

I'm currently struggling with achieving a graceful shutdown of a ZeroMQ XPUB/XSUB proxy. The [doc](http://api.zeromq.org/4-0:zmq-proxy) states that only termination of the ZMQ context makes `zmq::proxy` return. In my case, however, this results in a `SIGABRT`. Is that intended behavior or am I doing something wrong?

Note that I don't have a `zmq_proxy_steerable` available as I'm using an older ZMQ version (4.0.4).

My code looks as follows:

```
zmq::context_t c;
std::condition_variable cv;

std::thread t([&]() {
    zmq::socket_t xsub(c, ZMQ_XSUB);
    zmq::socket_t xpub(c, ZMQ_XPUB);
    xsub.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:*");
    xpub.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:*");
    cv.notify_all();
    zmq::proxy(xsub, xpub, NULL);
});

std::mutex m;
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);
cv.wait(lk);

c.close();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: http://grokbase.com/t/zeromq/zeromq-dev/143bx5ydcw/pattern-for-clean-shutdown-of-a-proxy-loop#201403126hzc7n830vcpqt5897x20ba3pc covers this issue and provides some history.